# StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di) returns false

Tags: printing

i am trying to print a raw data to the printer. i got my codes from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322090

in the code segment...

```
   Dim di As New DOCINFOW


    With di

        .pDocName = "My Visual Basic .NET RAW Document"        
        .pDataType = "TEXT"
        .pOutputFile = vbNull
    End With

 If OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero) Then
        If StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di) Then
            If StartPagePrinter(hPrinter) Then
                bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, dwWritten)
                EndPagePrinter(hPrinter)
            End If
            EndDocPrinter(hPrinter)
        End If
        ClosePrinter(hPrinter)
    End If
```

the first if returns TRUE but the **If StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di) Then** returns FALSE that's why further nested if cannot be catered. I have worked in this problem for hours searching, etc to no avail. Anybody who happened to encounter the same problem may have a solution. Thank you.

Comment: What is the last error? dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()

Comment: i tried printing on a network printer and the error displayed is just 0. I connected the printer directly to my PC and the code works

Comment: Are you calling GetLastWin32Error immediately after the StartDocPrinter fails?

Comment: when StartDocPrinter fails, it exists the loop and calls the GetLastWin32Error

Comment: If ClosePrinter is called before you call GetLastWin32Error, it will overwrite the last error with ERROR_SUCCESS (0).

Comment: yes that's right. btw the problem just fixed itself, i don't know why but i tried to print to different networked printer and it worked.